# Evaluate $I = \frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_ \rho} \frac {1}{z^n} \, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm having some difficulty calculating this integral :

> For $\rho > 0$ and $n \in \Bbb N$ calculate the value of the integral
>
> $$I = \frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_ \rho} \frac {1}{z^n} \, dz$$
>
> where $\gamma_ \rho$ is the circle centered at $0$ and radius $\rho$.

In evaluating this integral I tried to use the circle $\lvert z \rvert = \rho$ parametrized by $z(t) = \rho e^{it}$, with $t \in [0, 2\pi]$, then $dz/dt = i\rho e^{it}$ but I'm confused by the power $n$ in the integrand when I have to make the substitution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_C \frac 1{z^n} = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i\rho e^{it}}{\rho^n e^{itn}}=\frac i{\rho^{n-1}} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac 1{e^{it(n-1)}}$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: This first part was helpful but I'm not sure how to take it from here : $\frac i{\rho^{n-1}} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac 1{e^{it(n-1)}}dt = \frac i{\rho^{n-1}} \int_0^{2\pi}{e^{-it(n-1)}}dt$. Can I perform u-substitution for ${-it(n-1)}$? Say $u = {-it(n-1)} \to du = {-i(n-1)}dt \to dt = -\frac{1}{i(n-1)}du$. If I substitute back in the integral things get ugly, I get : $-\frac{1}{i(n-1)}\frac i{\rho^{n-1}} [e^{-it(n-1)}]^{t=2\pi}_{t=0}$. I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: @VonKar That is correct. You can go from  $e^{-it(n-1)}^{2\pi}_0=e^{-2\pi i(n-1)}-e^0$. Because n is an integer, $e^{-2\pi i}=1.$ Therefore he integral is zero.

Comment: @VonKar If my answer helped you, please click the checkmark by my answer to show that it helped you.

Comment: Sure! Sorry about that, I'm new here. Thanks again!